# Does the iOS platform provide background sync?

Tags: ios

If the user performs an action in an iOS app while offline (e.g. airplane mode), can the app complete the action (by sending data to its server) once the user is online, even if the user completely closed the app *before* going online?

I’m asking because Twitter and Facebook do not have this functionality. (If I post something while offline, then close the app and go online, the post will not be submitted until I start the app again.)

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I think this will only work, if the data will be sent to iCloud, because this is managed by the system

Comment: Somebody was mentioning using the wake up time for the updated location callback. But i guess it's pretty much a risky practice, beside unregular API usage. Another way may be with push notifications, but it sucks as much as polling i guess.

Comment: @FelixSFD, It will not work even when using CloudKit. This is because CloudKit is solely for transfers and it doesn't even work if the device is offline, you'd still need to cache data to use it with CloudKit. There isn't any possible way to do it without waiving the App Store Guidelines and potentially getting your app removed.

Answer (score 1):

No. If the user kills your app, it's gone. It can no longer execute any of your applications code. The best you can do is research [background tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html) and you then have ~10 minutes to execute your actions before it's automatically terminated (if the user doesn't do it before the OS).

You can store the actions in a Database ([Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html), [Realm](https://realm.io)) or even in NSUserDefaults. When the app comes online, you can periodically attempt to parse those actions and send the network requests with [exponential back-off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff). I imagine this is the process Facebook and Twitter use.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with @JoeyClover's answer.

If what you want to do is an HTTP POST, you should be able to set up an `NSURLSession` for background processing. The system should then take over submitting your post even if the app is not running. See Xcode's docs on NSURLSession for more information. (You can do the same thing for downloads with an HTTP GET, but that's not what you're asking about.)

The exception to this is if the user actually terminates your app by swiping up on it in the task list. In that case the system kills your background upload/download tasks. The info on that is in the section on `NSURLSessionConfiguration`. To quote Apple's docs:

> Use this method to initialize a configuration object suitable for
>   transferring data files while the app runs in the background. A
>   session configured with this object hands control of the transfers
>   over to the system, which handles the transfers in a separate process.
>   In iOS, this configuration makes it possible for transfers to continue
>   even when the app itself is suspended or terminated.
>
> If an iOS app is terminated by the system and relaunched, the app can
>   use the same identifier to create a new configuration object and
>   session and retrieve the status of transfers that were in progress at
>   the time of termination. This behavior applies only for normal
>   termination of the app by the system. **If the user terminates the app
>   from the multitasking screen, the system cancels all of the session’s
>   background transfers**. In addition, the system does not automatically
>   relaunch apps that were force quit by the user. The user must
>   explicitly relaunch the app before transfers can begin again.

(I bolded the key bit.)